# Converting Double to NSNumber in Swift Loses Accuracy

Tags: ios, swift, double, nsnumber

For some reason, certain Doubles in my Swift app are giving me trouble when converting to NSNumber, while some are not. My app needs to convert doubles with 2 decimal places (prices) to NSNumbers so they can be stored and retrieved using Core Data. For example, a few particular prices such as 79.99 would evaluate to 99.98999999999999 unless specifically formatted using NSNumber's doubleValue method.

Here selectedWarranty.price = 79.99 as shown in debugger

```
// item.price: NSNumber?       
// selectedWarranty.price: Double?  

item.price = NSNumber(double: selectedWarranty.price!)
```

I programmed some print statements to show how the conversion works out

```
Original double: 79.99
Converted to NSNumber: 79.98999999999999
.doubleValue Representation: 79.99
```

Can somebody explain if there is a reason why the initializer cannot surely keep 2 decimal places for every number? I would really like to store the prices in Core Data like they should be. Formatting every time it is displayed doesn't sound very convenient.

**UPDATE**:
Converted Core Data object to type NSDecimalNumber through data model, 79.99 and 99.99 no longer a problem, but now more manageable issue with different numbers...

```
Original double: 39.99
Converted to NSDecimalNumber: 39.99000000000001024
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Use `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `NSNumber` for currency.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57bdc2590dcf4abf47da28c2

Comment: 1> 79.99
$R0: Double = 79.989999999999994. But I tried other numbers, quite interesting.   
  2> 39.99
$R1: Double = 39.990000000000002
  3> 59.99
$R2: Double = 59.990000000000002
  4>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you're confusing some terms. `79.98999999999999` is higher precision than `79.99` (it has a longer decimal expansion), but lower accuracy (it deviates from the true value).

Secondly, NSNumber does not store neither `79.99` nor `79.98999999999999`. It stores the magnitude of the value according to the `IEEE 754` standard. What you're seeing is likely the consequence of the printing logic that's applied to convert that magnitude into a human readable number. In any case, you should not be relying on `Float` or `Double` to store values with a fixed precision. By their very nature, they sacrifice precision in order to gain a longer range of representable values.

You would be much better off representing prices as an `Int` of cents, or as an `NSDecimalNumber`.

Please refer to [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/3141234)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. NSDecimalNumber route seems best. My only question is how I can get the Core Data model to let me use that instead of NSNumber? I am not very experienced in this area

Comment: I don't know, try opening a new question for it. If you feel this answer satisfies your immediate question, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

That's how double works everywhere. If you need only 2 decimal places consider using integer/long instead adding point after second digit, when need to display the value.